# iOS: Correct way to dispose of view controllers and go back to main screen

Tags: ios, segue

I have a login screen, a second screen and a third screen. I want to have a button in the third screen to go back to the login screen and delete the current instances of second and third screen.

What I have is a push segue from login to second screen and a push segue from second to third screen. I've put a bar button item on the navigation bar of the third screen and attached a modal segue to it to go back to the login screen. On clicking I get a new login screen thats empty, this is just creating a new instance of it right? How do I delete the previous instances so that memory is saved? In Android we pass a flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to the intent that clears the other activities. Is there something analogous to this in iOS?

Comment: So are you using navigation controller for pushing segue?

Comment: @Mrunal Yes, each of the three screens is embedded in a navigation controller. Also the login screen that appears doesn't work, for some reason it is not embedded in a navigation controller, on trying to log in again it gives exception saying that push segues can only be used when the source is attached to a navigation controller.

Comment: Why not show the login screen as a modal view?

Comment: @NickWeaver Umm... what does that mean?

Comment: Here's a good read: [Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating new object on third screen just use the following code inside navigation bar button action method. Ur remaining objects will be destroyed automatically.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new instance of the Login View Controller and dispose all other controllers, your code should be like this.

```
   LoginViewController *loginController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginController"]; 
   UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
   [[(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] setRootViewController:navController];
```

**P.S:** *If you do not mind keeping the same instance of LoginViewController you had before, then user2894531's answer is correct*

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, but user2894531's answer is sufficient for me now.